# Stripe js is not showing selected theme styling - Angular 12

Tags: javascript, angular, stripe-payments, payment-gateway

This is my First time that I am integrating Stripe.js in angular project.
I have gone through documentation and implement it **(Stripe Card Element Method)**.
Stripe implemented and showing me card element in one input field.
I don't required single input field, I am looking for pre built themes for stripe element.
I added Appearance and client secret but does not picking the theme.

**payment-component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-payment',
  templateUrl: './payment.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./payment.component.css']
})
export class PaymentComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() {
   

   }
  
  ngOnInit(): void {
    const clientSecret = 'seti_1KawGlBBpoL4ww8PpzEwfTAU_secret_LHVHt3qcV8Cznw8b00vvFUVaaCFbLnc';
    const appearance = {
      theme: 'flat'
};
    var stripe   = Stripe('pk_test_51JkpiuBBpoL4ww8PpO2UfKSTE7M84aESVyaKUCWBqkxwQ3LRgOpQ2fh7hH4hxb2V9sA3e8DwvVIWoHurhryqdAHp00HVNutZkg');
    var elements = stripe.elements({ clientSecret, appearance});
    var cardElement = elements.create('card');
    cardElement.mount('#card-element');
    
  }

}
```

**payment-component.html**

```
<form action="/charge" method="post" id="payment-form">
  <div class="form-row">
    <label for="card-element">Credit or debit card</label>
    <div id="card-element"></div>
    <div id="card-errors" role="alert"></div>
  </div>
  <button>Add payment source</button>
</form>
```

**Output I got**
[Stripe Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jf52r.png)

**Theme I required looks alike**
[Theme output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Czajw.png)

Comment: Do you have any error in the console?

Comment: nothing... just a default stripejs warning of https

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the example you showed is `payment` element but you are using `card` element in your code.

The Elements Appearance API doesn’t support individual payment method Elements (such as CardElement) You should use `elements.create('payment')` ([API](https://stripe.com/docs/js/elements_object/create_payment_element)) to create a `payment` element.

Comment: do I create Token in Payment element as I was creating in card element?

Comment: in my scenario, user will enter card details, then stripe will generate token that will send to backend API to make payment. Is this possible with  Payment element?

Comment: Unlike CardElement which can be rendered without a clientSecret. The payment element requires a valid clientSecret for rendering. Therefore, you need to create a PaymentIntent at your backend first, and then pass the PaymentIntent's clientSecret to frontend to render the payment element

Comment: I have the same issue and I don't understand from this answer what can I do to fix it. Any help, please?